# Cron/Quartz Every N months

Tags: cron, quartz.net

The cron expression:

0 0 0 L 8/7 ?

Is described by [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) as:

"At 00:00:00am, on the last day of the month, every 7 months starting in August"

However, when I choose to see the next execution dates I get:

Thu Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2017
Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2018
Sat Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2019
Mon Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2020
Tue Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2021
Wed Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2022
Thu Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2023
Sat Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2024

Which really is "every 12 months starting in August". I was expecting to get a 7-month period, but I suspect everything resets when you cross the January threshold.

Is there any way I can actually get periodic values such as every n months or every n weeks or is that not really possible out of the box with cron?

Comment: Don't think the website you link to is correct. I think the every x months feature only works when x divides 12. (ie 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 or 12)

Comment: It seems that you can't schedule with `8/7` because of the year change. This could be a bug in Quartz. Just open a issue and hear what the devs have to say about it.

Comment: @Rabban I checked the source and yes, it resets when the year changes. I just wanted to find out if that is a bug or by design ( for example if crontab does the same in *nix).

Comment: I think this is by design. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron  -  `Note that frequencies in general cannot be expressed; only step values which evenly divide their range express accurate frequencies ...`

Comment: @sgmoore good point! I wonder if there is any other library that would work well with frequencies.

Comment: Never tried it, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005920/quartz-net-repeat-on-day-n-of-every-m-months