# CronExpression every 2 days

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I know this question was asked before. But the answers in those questions are not correct in my opinion.

I want to have a CronExpression for (Quartz) that schedules every 2 days.
The CronExpression "should be" `0 0 0 1/2 * ? *`.

BUT: Starting today (9th October 2017) [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) shows that this is not true. This expression basically means: schedule every 2 days starting on the first of each month. That means: starting on 9th October 2017 the next times are:

Wednesday, October 11, 2017 12:00 AM
Friday, October 13, 2017 12:00 AM
Sunday, October 15, 2017 12:00 AM
Tuesday, October 17, 2017 12:00 AM
Thursday, October 19, 2017 12:00 AM
Saturday, October 21, 2017 12:00 AM
Monday, October 23, 2017 12:00 AM
Wednesday, October 25, 2017 12:00 AM
Friday, October 27, 2017 12:00 AM
Sunday, October 29, 2017 12:00 AM
**Tuesday, October 31, 2017 12:00 AM

Wednesday, November 1, 2017 12:00 AM**

As you can see: There is only 1 day between the two last times.

So when I'm using [freeformatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) to describe the cronexpression it states:

> At 00:00:00am, every 2 days starting on the 1st, every month

Well that is shown in the listed times above. But I need something that correctly fires every 2 days.

Tuesday, October 31, 2017 12:00 AM
Thursday, November 2, 2017 12:00 AM

and so on.

Apparently the simple trigger from quartz is not a real option for me!

Comment: In cron you could try day of week instead of day of month: `0 0 * * */2`

Comment: This has basically the same result but on the week basis.

Comment: @Naxos84 why is SimpleTrigger not an option you? to preserve context when we move forward to next month SimpleTrigger is the way to go.

Comment: Because as Puchacz mentioned in his answer my understanding of cron expressions was wrong. After more research I found that my problem can be solved with a org.quartz.CalendarIntervalTrigger. Cause my root problem was daylight saving time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becouse you misunderstood how cron expression works. For every month it will starts from first day of month. If it would work otherly, the next month wouldn't fit 1/2 part of expression.

For more detailed explanation, look here:

[Quartz.net - Repeat on day n, of every m months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005920/quartz-net-repeat-on-day-n-of-every-m-months?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: That might be correct. But with all your explanations on this and other questions I think I now understand how and what to use.

Comment: That's great to hear! :)